# All Possible Bit Combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose I have a table:

```
id      val
 0       1
 1       2
 2       4
```

I am looking for SQL that would return me all the bitwise combinations of the `val` column that are possible. So as an example, from the table above I would expect the following possible `val` combinations:

```
1  -- from original table id: 0
2  -- from original table id: 1
3  -- combination of id: 0 & 1
4  -- from original table id: 2
5  -- combination of id: 0 & 2
6  -- combination of id: 1 & 2
7  -- combination of id: 0 & 1 & 2
```

Comment: are you prepared to use temp tables and cursors/stored procedure program logic?  I'm presuming you want n records, so there could be 20+ records for example (which still has reasonable output number of records!)

Comment: bit-twiddling in a database is rarely a good idea. If you want to store multiple facts, store multiple rows - don't cram them all into a single column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This query just returns all combinations of sum(val), possibly not what you are looking for**. If you are looking for bitwise & you should use `t.val & cur.val` (thanks @Andrew Deighton)
(I didn't create the t table, instead I build it dynamically. You wont need that)

```
with t as
    (select 0 as id, 1 as val union all
     select 1 as id, 2 as val union all
     select 2 as id, 4 as val ),
 cur as 
    ( select id, val  from t union all
      select t.id, t.val + cur.val from cur join t on cur.id>t.id)
 select val
  from cur
order by val
```

**OUTPUT**

```
val
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

If you add a new record with val=8 you will get:

```
val
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Comment: that doesn't do any bitwise '&' operations that I can see though

Comment: would that not do it though if you used the &, not the + operator?

Comment: with t as
    (select 0 as id, 1 as val union all
     select 1 as id, 2 as val union all
     select 2 as id, 4 as val ),
 cur as 
    ( select id, val  from t union all
      select t.id, t.val & cur.val from cur join t on cur.id>t.id)
 select val
  from cur
order by val

Comment: The output that way is 0
0
0
0
1
2
4

Answer (score 0):

with your table called aTable - i came up with this

```
CREATE TABLE #combo (z bigint);

DECLARE @CNT integer;

SELECT @CNT = COUNT(0) FROM aTable;

DECLARE @I int;
SET @I = 0
WHILE @I < POWER(2, @CNT)
BEGIN
    INSERT #combo VALUES(@I);
    SET @I = @I + 1;
END

--select * from #combo;

;with cte as (select *, row_number() over (order by id) as rn from aTable),
    combs as (select c1.z,cte.rn, cte.val,  POWER(2, cte.rn -1) & c1.z as flag  from cte join #combo c1 ON POWER(2, cte.rn -1) & c1.z != 0 )


select *, row_number() over (partition by z order by rn) as lev, val final_val into #perms from combs  order by z,rn;

--select * from #perms;

DECLARE @depth as integer;
SET @depth = 2;



WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM #perms WHERE lev = @depth)
begin

    UPDATE #perms 
    SET #perms.final_val = p.final_val & #perms.val
FROM
  #perms
INNER JOIN
  #perms p
ON
  p.lev = #perms.lev - 1 AND p.z = #perms.z 

  set @depth = @depth + 1;

end

select #perms.z,#perms.final_val from #perms join (SELECT p.z, max(p.lev) maxz FROM #perms p GROUP BY z) DQ ON #perms.lev = dq.maxz and dq.z = #perms.z order by #perms.z;

DROP TABLE #combo;
DROP TABLE #perms;
```

---

or even

```
with t as
    (select * from atable),
 cur as 
    ( select id, val  from t union all
      select t.id, t.val & cur.val from cur join t on cur.id>t.id)
 select id,val
  from cur
order by id
```